# how inserting foreach loop all final result in a variable in php?

Tags: php, foreach

how inserting foreach loop all final result in a variable in php.

for example i have three array :

```
$myarray = ('a','b','c');
foreach($myarray as $myarray){
$text = $myarray;
}
echo $text;//i want echo abc but this code only print c.
```

i want taht code printing all final into a like $text and echo out a loop.

i know this code work nice but i want have all of the result out of loop

```
$myarray = ('a','b','c');
foreach($myarray as $myarray){
$text = $myarray;
echo $text;
}
```

please help.

thank you in advance from all friend.

Comment: Google: `PHP implode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$myarray = ('a','b','c');
$text = '';
foreach($myarray as $element){
  $text .= $element;
}
echo $text;
```

An alternative would be something like that:

```
<?php
$myarray = ('a','b','c');
echo implode('', $myarray);
```

Comment: very very thanks. i want like this code that able echo final result out of foreach loop not in foreach loop . very very thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = [];
$myarray = ['a','b','c'];
foreach($myarray as $element) {
  $text[] = $element; // append a new element to the array $text
  // ok, kinda useless since $text==$myarray after the loop
  // but ....it's only an example
}
echo join(', ', $text); see // http://docs.php.net/join
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `implode()`:

```
<?php
$myarray = ('a','b','c');
echo implode('', $myarray);
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php)